# How to assign null to boolean in ternary operator

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I can't able to assign null if two conditions not satisfied

```
bool? flag=   check_all_permission = mou_pr.insert_permission == "Y" ? true : (mou_pr.insert_permission=="N"?false: null) ,
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In general, please always indicate the exact error (like here, it's a compilation error) you get, if applicable. This will help as much the potential answerers as yourself to debug and understand the problem.

Comment: What are you trying to d here check_all_permission = mou_pr.insert_permission == "Y" 

It will give Compailation error

Comment: @Zeeshan that looks like assignment to two things, nothing unusual or illegal

Answer (score 3):

You need to help the compiler understand the *type* of `null` you mean:

```cs
? false : (bool?)null
```

although a switch expression might be clearer:

```cs
bool? flag = check_all_permission = mou_pr.insert_permission switch
{
    "Y" => true,
    "N" => false,
    _ => null,
};
```